# Restart azure web app instances individually via Azure CLI

Tags: azure-cli

I have a situation where our webapp has multiple instances, and these instances all try to use the same assemblies upon startup around the same time. I am looking to find out if it's possible to restart each instance for an azure webpp. If so I just need some guidance on Azure CLI command that would allow this.

I researched `az webapp restart`, this seems to restart all the instances right away. What I'd like to do is create a script that would allow me to place a delay for each instance start up. I will most likely need to get a list of instances which `az webapp list-instances` seems to solve but I am not sure how to execute the restart for each.

Basically I am trying to mimic the "Advanced application restart" under the "Diagnose and solve problems" blade in Azure portal

Answer (score 1):

Using rest api could meet your need. Just like what you mimic from the **"Advanced application restart"**, you could stop the instances' process to make it restart one by one. Here is the steps:

1. Get instance name by api: [List Instance Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listinstanceidentifiers). You could also do it using cli command: `az webapp list-instances`.
   [image]
2. Use the instance name to [List Instance Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listinstanceprocesses). Get the pid of the w3wp process.
   [image]
3. [Delete Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/deleteprocess) by the pid to make the instance restart automatically. Go to this site to check if the process restart or not: `https://{your-site-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/ProcessExplorer/`

Comment: Does my post help? You could let me know if you have other consideration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue is that its not fully using the Azure CLI. The Azure RM REST calls use a different authentication system which is non-trivial to understand and use.